# Reset Permissions like Camera for iOS Apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios-permissions

When I develop an app for iOS (iPhone/ iPad) and I need to request permissions. When I use the camera I need to request the camera permission. This can only be done once.

**Is there a way to reset initial given permissions at least when I develop an app?**

In this way I could check different scenarios for requesting the initial app permissions.

**Note: I want to get the initial permission request popup message again.**

Comment: try to delete and reinstall the app. you may get the same popups again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iPad remembering camera permissions after delete—how to clear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726354/ipad-remembering-camera-permissions-after-delete-how-to-clear)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy.

This will reset all location, camera and microphone permissions. 
It cannot be done on a per app basis.

Comment: Basically, this forces you to have dedicated test devices, not use your own personal daily phone, where it would be too annoying to constantly recent.

Comment: apple does everything to make the developer happy: good documentation, an amazing IDE, easy APIs. < /s>

Comment: It doesn't work for me. iOS 14.3 beta (simulator). I press the button, after that I'm going to Settings -> Privacy and it's like I didn't do anything

Answer (score 22):

Another way around this is to change your bundle id. With each new bundle id you provide, it is like a fresh install of the app. Remember to change it back to the original bundle id after testing :)

Comment: do you only have to change it in one place

Comment: Yes, its where you set the bundle id from the project file under general

Answer (score 5):

To reset all the Location & Privacy permissions you can go to:

> Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy

To view what Apps have what services and to turn it off for individual services you can go to:

> Settings > Privacy > The service you want to view

Here you can turn off the service for individual apps, note that this doesn't mean you'll get the popup message again it just means that app will not use that service.

Comment: correct, thanks for the ; Settings > Privacy > The service you want to view

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me:
Windows -> Devices And Simulators -> Installed Apps section, remove the app from there using the - button.
This resets the permissions every time with a fresh install afterwards.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions

Comment: this is not working for me, iphone 12, 14.2

Comment: This worked for me. Xcode 14.1, iOS 16.3. Just deleting the app didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If testing on a real device, uninstalling the app seems to work for me.

Comment: I think this is true if you only do a sideload (ad-hoc profile) but not for apps that have come from the app store at some point. In that case, the permissions seem to be retained.

Comment: For xcode run actions, the permissions seem to be permanent too.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work now. On my iOS 13.4.5 device, uninstalling the app, then reinstalling it retains the previously granted permissions, so you cannot test the permissions prompt again

Answer (score 0):

Another way to reset permissions on iOS simulator is to delete the appropriate database row from the `access` table in `$SIMULATOR_DEVICE_DIRECTORY/data/Library/TCC/TCC.db`. This can be done per app / service basis.