# iOS app crashed even after reinstalled, but not for the new users

Tags: ios, swift, crash

Some of my old app users are experiencing app crashes for a certain step after I updated the app. Even when they tried to delete the app and reinstalled it, it's still crashing. However, the app doesn't crash for new users.

How does that happen? When a user completely deletes the app and reinstalls it from the AppStore, the user should be like a new user, right? How come the new users don't crash while the users who re-install the app keep crashing?

Is there something remaining in the device even after the user deletes the app?

Comment: Do you have any data come from server?

Answer (score 1):

If you use keychain functionality that may persist across uninstalls and reinstalls. That, in theory, is the only data that should persist with that behavior.

Without more code or details it's hard to know what the problem might be, but to your question "Is there something remained in the device...": yes, keychain information.

Comment: ^^ is the only reason it should persist. Correct way would be to reset that specific keychain information upon re-download of application.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that does remain in the device after uninstalling an app is privacy settings ([Relevant SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726354/ipad-remembering-camera-permissions-after-delete-how-to-clear)).

Perhaps you're trying to access something incorrectly with your update?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any database in your project?

If yes we need to take care of version migration.