# IPhone remembers Location Permissions after uninstalling

Tags: ios, permissions

My problem is simply that after I delete my app from testflight it seems to remember the location permissions the next time i download the app. Is this normal behavior?

I found this post [iPad remembering camera permissions after delete—how to clear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726354/ipad-remembering-camera-permissions-after-delete-how-to-clear), but its from 2014. Is this correct and is it just the same on location permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the normal behavior since iOS 9 or 10. You can reset the permissions on the device's Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy.

Comment: Note, that this will reset permissions for all apps on your iPhone, not only for the tested one.