# How to identify on iOS if user enabled zoom accessibility feature?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, accessibility, voiceover

Is there a way to identify programmatically if the user has the "zoom" accessibility feature toggled on?

I'm referring to the feature where you can:

- Double-tap three fingers to toggle zoom on off
- Drag with three finger to change scroll area of the screen.
- Use two fingers to scroll on current area of the screen.

When zoom is toggle on and screen is zoomed there is no change in `UIScreen.main.scale`

Something similar to UAZoomEnabled from the MacOs UniversalAccess.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way, but if your goal is to warn the user that your app uses gestures that conflict with Zoom, you can call `UIAccessibility.registerGestureConflictWithZoom()` and the OS will provide a message to the user if they have zoom enabled. You shouldn't try to provide your own messaging. See details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69088232/how-to-registergestureconflictwithzoom-correctly (But it's a good question if you want to adapt your app rather than ask the user to disabled zoom.)

Comment: I would like to disable ads to users that enable this feature.
What you are suggesting is an interesting work around, I'll investigate this.

Comment: @RobNapier `UIAccessibility.registerGestureConflictWithZoom()` won't help. it is just a one time message to the user. The function `override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)` is triggered when an external touch event is happening so it might suggest the user is using zoom but it is not 100% guarantee. I've submitted to apple a feature request.